# .htaccess RewriteRule with form parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

www.example.com/`Search.php?q=mySearchString` this is my search link. I want to change it to

www.example.com/`Search/mySearchString`

Then I tried below rule in my .htaccess file but it looks like -> `Search/?q=mySearchString`
How I can eliminate `?q=` from address

in .htaccess file I add a rule like this;

```
RewriteRule ^Search/(.*)$ Search.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```

Also I send search query with a form and form's method is 'GET'

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-left" method="GET" action="Search/">
    <input name="q" type="text" />
 </form>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your search input to:

```
<input name="query" type="text" />
```

Then use these two rules:

```
# If someone searches /Search/?query=search+string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=([^&]+)
# Redirect to /Search/search+string
RewriteRule ^Search/$ Search/%1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Match the redirect from the rule above and serve up results
RewriteRule ^Search/(.*)$ Search.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```